# Return the total count of line days from multiple occurences for a single patient from a date range

Tags: sql, vb.net, reporting-services

I am extremely new at this but I have been able to work out how to return the total number of line days for a particular patient for an individual parameter. See Current Results Data Table.

Each patient is only counted once, irrespective of how many lines they have in.
The problem I have is that when line days overlap. I need to be able to return the total number of line days for a patient.

Final Column in Table has been manually added.

Current Results:

[image]

```
SELECT        
PendingRangeSignals.PendingOrderID, 
PendingOrders.PatientID, 
Parameters.ParameterName, 


(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, PendingRangeSignals.StartTime, 103) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hh, PendingRangeSignals.StartTime)) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(mi, PendingRangeSignals.StartTime)), 2) AS Date) as "Start Time Column",

(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, RangeSignals.EndTime, 103) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hh, RangeSignals.EndTime)) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(mi, RangeSignals.EndTime)), 2) AS Date) as "End Time Column",

iif(datepart(hh,PendingRangeSignals.StartTime)>= 0 OR 

CASE
    WHEN RangeSignals.EndTime IS NULL
    THEN datediff(hh,PendingRangeSignals.StartTime,isnull(RangeSignals.EndTime,getdate()))
    ELSE datediff(hh,PendingRangeSignals.StartTime,RangeSignals.EndTime)
END < 24,

datediff(d,iif(PendingRangeSignals.StartTime < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0), DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0),PendingRangeSignals.StartTime)  , dateadd(day,1,isnull(RangeSignals.EndTime,getdate()))),
 datediff(d,iif(PendingRangeSignals.StartTime < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0), DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0),PendingRangeSignals.StartTime)  , isnull(RangeSignals.EndTime,getdate()))) as "LineDaysinMonth"

FROM
PendingRangeSignals INNER JOIN
PendingOrders ON PendingRangeSignals.PendingOrderID = PendingOrders.PendingOrderID INNER JOIN
Parameters ON PendingRangeSignals.ParameterID = Parameters.ParameterID
LEFT JOIN RangeSignals ON RangeSignals.ParameterID = Parameters.ParameterID and RangeSignals.PatientID = PendingOrders.PatientID and PendingRangeSignals.StartTime = RangeSignals.StartTime

WHERE
(PendingOrders.PatientID = 2105) and pendingorders.Status = 5  and ((datepart(month,RangeSignals.EndTime) = datepart(month,getdate())) or RangeSignals.EndTime is null) and [Parameters].ParameterID IN (1046, 1372, 8546, 1051, 8532, 8538, 1375, 8531, 8888)
```

Comment: Given that a patient can have lines put in and taken out, the "days with a line" are not necessarily continuous.  I don't think this can be solve with a single query.  You might have to get all the data, and then loop through it to count the specific calendar days.

Comment: This would probably be easier to read (and to solve) if you eliminated extraneous things (such as pendingorders.Status = 5) to minimize to exactly the question that you're trying to solve. Also, providing a simplified table structure would be helpful.

Comment: what does it mean " when line days overlap"? please show samples of tables.

Comment: @koriander, if you look at the sample data, the two rows for patient 2005 have overlapping line days.  So do the 2nd and 3rd rows for patient 2105.

Comment: ok, and what exactly means "Line Days in Month"? for the last row, does it mean the patient needs 3 days in December and 3 days in January? or only 3 days in the period? is this effective days or planned days? I also don't see why you need two selects for start time and end time in the query. Without data on the source tables we can only guess at best.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback and questions.

Comment: @DanBracuk - For each day of the month we count if current patients have a line. If yes = 1, No = 0 (if they have more than one line they still only score 1 for that day) and at present the researchers are not interested in exactly how long each day the line was in.

Comment: @koriander - "Line Days in Month" is the total days that a patient had a particular line insitu for this month. I have been able to exclude the 3 days in Dec and only count the 3 relevant days in Jan but as the patient has another line that continues after the 3rd then this figure is not needed and this "overlap" is where I cannot figure out how to exclude this information.     The two start and end times was the only was I could figure out how to convert the server time to an easier format.           Where do I get data on the source tables to assist you in helping me?

Comment: @TomH - If I remove the pendingorders.Status = 5 I get erroneous data that makes interpretation harder. Do you mean I should remove the additional information and only provide the relevant parameters? Can you point me towards a simplified table structure so I know what you mean and then I may be able to provide clearer information.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand now, I would suggest:

1) create a table "days" with numbers 0-31: days(day)

2) create a subquery that returns the calendar days for the month you want, e.g., a simplified example for months with 31 days.

```
(SELECT cast('2016-01-01' + interval `day` day as date) mydate
        FROM days) mymonth
```

3) join your patient line records with this subquery and use "distinct" to remove duplicate dates, e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT patientid, count(patientid) as `LineDays`
FROM   (SELECT cast('2016-01-01' + interval `day` day as date) mydate
        FROM days) mymonth
LEFT JOIN rangesignals on (mydate between startDate and endDate)
GROUP BY patientid;
```

I simplified time to date and ignored pendingsignals but I think you'll get the idea. I'm not totally sure that distinct will remove dupe dates before group by (I think not), but if so, you can do it with another subquery. And I think if you are using MS-SQL there might be another way to do a calendar. If you create the sqlfiddle then it is easy to test.